# HTML: Items nesting within the item that comes before to it

Tags: html

[image: Individual objects appearing inside of the one that comes previous]

I believe it has something to do with the `<div>` tag. I'd prefer not to post my code as its a mix of python and HTML and am asking particularly if anyone has seen this specific type of error before.

Comment: Just by looking at the picture, one thing comes to mind (total guess).  It is possible that there is an issue with a closing div tag, meaning that the next item is added before the preceding div is closed.  I would check it out in your editor but a common issue is a poorly placed closing div tag inside a for loop.

Comment: If it's not an issue with the closing `div` tag, then it seems like you have positioned `div's` absolute, in a relative positioned `div` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that in my HTML generated by a Python for loop, I was not closing the `div` tag which then caused this structure to render.